# In case of exception Instead of getting code 404 (or others) i get the 200 and the html tags

Tags: android, ajax

Before explaining the problem, let me inform you, that I'm a newbie in programming world (hope for your understanding).

I'm trying to build an android application, which requires some http calls to be invoked.

The calls are directed to the server which uses ajax (If the exception occurs, the server redirects the user to another page (to display the error) instead of sending the exception to him)

What i want is:

```
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response=null;
    response = getHttpClient().execute(get, getHttpContext());
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode==404)
       {
             //send the user to login again
       }

    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

But instead of giving me the error 404, i get the status 200 and the variable response is filled with the web site html tags (the following code is a value of responseString):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
        <head runat="server">
            <title>Вход</title>
            <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/p/Content/projectThemes/ar/icon.ico" />
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/p/Content/projectThemes/ar/!css-cache-29051821.css" />
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/p/Content/!css-cache--56281661.css" />
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/p/Content/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/p/Content/!css-cache-372860782.css" />
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/p/Content/components/spreadsheet-component.css" />
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/p/Plugins/AutorizeRegistration/Content/text-styles.css" />
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/p/Plugins/AutorizeRegistration/content/recomended-browsers.css" />
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/p/Plugins/Cabinet/content/cabinet-content.css" />
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/p/Plugins/CommonEditorsPlugin/Content/!css-cache--1229552186.css" />
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/p/Plugins/CommonFilesStorePlugin/Content/file-editor.css" />

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var rootDir = "/p/ru/";
                var filesRootDir = "/p/";
            </script>

                    <script src="/p/Scripts/cache/js--314828493.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>                <script src="/p/Scripts/ie6/warning.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->                <script src="/p/Scripts/cache/js-695581335.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="outer-wrapper">
                <div id="top-right-blocks-exp">



    </div>
                <div id="shortcuts-container">

    //..................... and a lot of more html >>>>>>>>>>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: I just want to point out that you're missing a semicolon in the declaration of `statusCode`

Comment: what response your are getting..share your code and response

Comment: @MeenalSharma, i've added some code and the response.

Comment: @AmolTate, not yet. I'm afraid, i'll have to ask the server-guys to do something on their side

Comment: Yes my next suggestion would be like this only.

Comment: there is an issue with server side...if your request is correct..may be issue is with server code

Comment: This is what you are getting from server side, You can change response by doing server side coding to return response of a webcall.

Comment: @DeepakPanwar,yes, but i thought it is not the best decision. The approach i expect use is to check whether the status code is 200 (success) or another (for example 404, 400)

Comment: 200(Success) it means server return you some result. Result can be according to what you had decided to show. At server side you have to throw exception when you want that some parameter or something missing in url .

Comment: As you had mentioned, the server redirects the user to another page (to display the error) instead of sending the exception to him). Thats why it is throwing to html tags with success.

Comment: @DeepakPanwar, is it possible to send for example 404 code? (When i asked some server-guys about it, they told me that in order to get the code, i need to make an ajax call, but android as i know can't.) (As i said, i am a beginner, please don't judge if  i say something stupid) Thanks

Comment: The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested. This all will be done from server side , not from your end, tell server guy not to redirect to another url, just throw exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the server exception handling (don't know why, but only with the 401 unauthorized). the decision was to:

### 1. Put the following into the server:

```
                   if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
                        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                        Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        Response.StatusDescription = "Unauthorized";
                        Response.ContentType = "text/json";
                        Response.Write("[]");
                        Response.SuppressContent = false;
                        Response.End();
                        //filterContext.Result= new HttpStatusCodeResult(401, "Unauthorized");
                        return;
                    }
```

## 2. Put the header into the HttpGet (in Android code):

```
        HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        mHttpGet .setHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

Huge Thanks to all those, who helped me!(Especially @DeepakPanwar)